# Attempting to use plugin to addslashes in a template not working

Tags: plugin, text-formatting, formatting, phpstringfun

I am fairly new to EE so please bare with me. I have an issue where I want to use `addslashes()` on a template tag that is in an array.

```
$product_array["{ProductEntryID}"][] = array(
    'CustomizationNotes' => "{CustomizationNotes}",
);
```

I've used two different plugins with success on my local development environment [Format Characters](https://github.com/amphibian/format_characters.ee_addon) and 
[PHPStringFun](http://engaging.net/products/phpstringfun). However when I attempt to use them on the production site nothing is output.

Not sure where to go from here any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Can you, please, update your question with more details on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a template?  Is PHP Turned on with PHP Parsing set to after? As Robson states, need more information otherwise we're just guessing at what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This smacks of [Parse order](http://loweblog.com/downloads/ee-parse-order.pdf), as Robson and Peter suggest.

if that piece of PHP code is on a template somewhere, I van only assume you want the tags filled in BEFORE the php is executed, therefor set your template to PHP `On` on `Output`. You can also add the addslashes into your php array creation.

By example, first lets echo out the array so we can see what happens when :

```
<?php 
$product_array["{ProductEntryID}"][] = array(
  'CustomizationNotes' => addslashes("{CustomizationNotes}"),
);
print "<pre>".print_r($product_array,1)."</pre>";
?>
<span>I am not a number, I am a free span!</span>
```

assuming `{ProductEntryID}` evaluates to '10' and `{CustomizationNotes}` evaluates to "Don't use apostrophies" then, with PHP on Outout the first thing to happen is the tags are parsed, so your template becomes :

```
<?php
$product_array["10"][] = array(
  'CustomizationNotes' => addslashes("Don't use apostrophies"),
);
print "<pre>".print_r($product_array,1)."</pre>";
?>
<span>I am not a number, I am a free span!</span>
```

And neareer the end the php is evaluated so the source you end up with is :

```
<pre>Array\n
(\n
    [10] => Array\n
        (\n
            [0] => Array\n
                (\n
                    [CustomizationNotes] => Don\'t use apostrophies\n
                )\n
\n
    )\n
\n
)\n
</pre>
<span>I am not a number, I am a free span!</span>
```